# MDX to calculate difference between sales amount between 2 dates

Tags: mdx

I have a `Cube` with a `Date dimension hierarchy` (Calendar,Year,Month,Week,Day) and Measure as `SalesData`, would like to add a calculated measure which would give me the `SalesData` for the selected date and the last date of the Previous Month.

Calendar Hierarchy is as follows

```
Date - Dimension 
Calendar - Hierarchy 
Year - [Date].[Calendar].[Year]
Quarter - [Date].[Calendar].[Quarter] 
Month - [Date].[Calendar].[Month] 
Week - [Date].[Calendar].[Week] 
Day - [Date].[Calendar].[Day]
```

Measures
    [Sales]

New Calculated Member need to be created - say [SalesMTD] 
Requirement is when a user select any date say 3 March 2016, the calculated member should give Sales as follows

```
[SalesMTD] = [Sales] on 3 March 2016 - [Sales] on 29 Feb 2016
```

Can someone please help me write an `MDX query` for the Calculated Measure ?

Your help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Sales Last Month]

AS ([Date].[Months].CURRENTMEMBER.PREVMEMBER, [Measures].[sales])

, VISIBLE = 1  ;
```

Then write another calculation using the above calculations

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Sales Difference]

AS ([Measures].[Revenue]-[Measures].[Sales Last Month])

, VISIBLE = 1  ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have updated the question above to provide more accurate details. Can you please take a look, and thanks vm for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

```
with member measures.SalesDataLastDaylasMonth
as
[Date].[Calendar].currentmember.firstsibling.lag(1)
//or [Date].[Calendar].currentmember.firstsibling.prevmember

select {measures.SalesData, measures.SalesDataLastDaylasMonth} on 0,
[Date].[Calendar].[Day].members on 1
from [Some Cube]
```

Here `currentmember.firstsibling.prevmember` fetches the member prior to the first day in the list of days in the current month.

Also, you can obviously create this member in a cube instead of having it query scoped like this. The syntax would be similar to the above answer.

**Based upon your edit**

There are multiple ways of getting to it. Below are some:

```
with member Measures.[SalesMTD]
as
Measures.[Sales]
-
(Measures.[Sales],Ancestor([Date].[Calendar].currentmember, [Date].[Calendar].[Month]).firstchild.firstchild)
//(Measures.[Sales],[Date].[Calendar].currentmember.parent.parent.firstchild.firstchild.lag(1))
//(Measures.[Sales],[Date].[Calendar].currentmember.parent.parent.firstchild.firstchild.prevmember)

select Measures.[SalesMTD] on 0,
[Date].[Calendar].[Day].members on 1
from [Some Cube]
```

The first approach is the neatest.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have updated the question above to provide more accurate details. Can you please take a look, and thanks vm for your assistance.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However seems like the usage of CurrentMember causing issues when I use the Calculated member in the Slicer. Can you please take a look and probably update the MDX query so that the Calculated member shows correct values when used in the Slicer.